# Disabling how changing an HTML file name in a Doc Lib modifies the file contents

Tags: 2007, document-library, html

SharePoint version: 2007

I am seeing a weird issue. When changing the name of a .htm file in a document library (Check Out > Edit Properties > Change the Name Field > Check In), it seems that SharePoint is changing details inside the file.

For example, the left (SharePoint changed file) has some extra xml elements, more attributes in the html element, and the img src was changed.

[image: Left is changed, right is original in this compare]

The big issue for me is that the img src attrubute is changing. I have base64 data in that attribute, which is being reduced to 256 characters.

**Anyone have any ideas on how to turn off this behavior?**

Before HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id='imgsmall0' src="data:image/png;base64,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">
        <img id='imgsmall1' src="data:image/png;base64,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">
    </body>
</html>
```

After HTML:

```
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">    
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:Release_x0020__x0023_ msdt:dt="string"></mso:Release_x0020__x0023_>
<mso:ContentType msdt:dt="string">Document</mso:ContentType>
<mso:Project_x0020_Name msdt:dt="string"></mso:Project_x0020_Name>
<mso:Doc_x0020_Type msdt:dt="string">TBD</mso:Doc_x0020_Type>
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
</xml><![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id='imgsmall0' src="data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL/wAARCACtAggDASIAAhEBAx">
        <img id='imgsmall1' src="data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL/wAARCAAhAJ8DASIAAhEBAx">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could not find any real help online or from M$, but I replaced all my image tags with the following and it seems to stop the image corruption:

```
<img id='imgsmall0' src=""></a><script>var imgSrcData0 = "img data here instead of in the src of img"; document.getElementById("imgsmall0").src = imgSrcData0;</script>
```